# why websocat or wscat in background with nohup, disown, bg, &, &! don't work

Tags: shell-script, tty, background-process, nohup, disown

The question is about running a bash script in background with the ability to logout and the process to continue. The issue is that websocat and wscat don't like when I close the terminal or logout.......

**** NOTE : the script.sh does work when just do `script.sh` it have the execute permission and there is no error in the script

But when I'm trying nohup, disown, bg, &, &! ===>>>> all of those don't work :(

the content of script.sh

```
wscat -c "wss://somewebsocketstream" > file
```

when I run nohup `appending output to nohup.out` and when I hit enter, the script.sh stops

```
nohup /script.sh
```

when I add `&` I get `[1]  + suspended (tty input)  nohup` and .sh stops

when I add `&!`

whitout `nohup` and only `script.sh &` I get `[1]  + suspended (tty input)` when I type any key on the keyboard

only `script.sh &!` nothing happens, I see it in top but no activity :(

when I try `bg script.sh` I get `bg: job not found`

when I try `script.sh 2>&1 &` or `script.sh &> /dev/null &` I get `[1]  + suspended (tty input)   2>&1`

Comment: WHat happen when you try `nohup command &`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov when I do `nohup ....sh &` I get `appending output to nohup.out` and when I type enter to do something else I get `[1]  + suspended (tty input)  nohup`

Comment: Have you check after above command if the program work?

Comment: @RomeoNinov when I see `suspended (tty input)` in the terminal, the process remains inactive and don't work. I have to do `jobs` to get the pid and kill it manually

Comment: Please edit your question to not have the question in the title but the body, and proofread for grammar and punctuation. The question also has some unnecessary "formatting" making it difficult to read (ex. `===>>>>`). The initial paragraph could be better phrased to contain the question.

Comment: What are the `.sh`, `/....sh` and `...sh` commands supposed to do? You can check nohup.out to see the output from running your commands with nohup, offering insight into what is happening.

Comment: @Vilinkameni sorry for the confusion, it's script.sh I modified the question. In other words when I only do `script.sh` it's all good, but when I add nohup or & nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Hi found a python way to do it (so `nohup`, `&`, etc works)

https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/

```
pip3 install websocket-client
```

in the .py

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection('wss:.....')
print(ws.recv())
stubfile = open('/pathto.file', 'w+')
stubfile.write(ws.recv())
ws.close()
```

this py gets 1 message from the `wss://` and saves it in a file

I can also add this `.py` in my crontab -e ....

Comment: There is no explicit question in the question, but judging by the title I say the question is "why don't these work?". The answer answers "how to get the result I want?". These are *different* questions. **The answer does not answer "why?" at all.** You answered your own question. Please consider editing the question or/and the answer, so they match. The easiest way may be to drop "why?" and explicitly ask the question you were willing to answer. If you want to keep "why?" in the hope someone will answer *it* eventually, then your answer is a partial answer at most.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I was unable to find the answer of the why... so I found an other solution that works